# Problems to POST data in API by HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, api, dotnet-httpclient

My code is showing the the following error: "Error: 401 Not Authorized" when I post the data.

My class:

```
public class APICommands : IDisposable
{
    public APICommands()
    {
        this.HttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

        // Set authentication.
        this.HttpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        this.HttpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@myemail.com", "mypassword");

        this.HttpClient = new HttpClient(this.HttpClientHandler);

        this.HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.myhost.com");

        this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    private HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

    private HttpClientHandler HttpClientHandler { get; set; }

    public async Task<JsonResultBoleto> CreateClient(string name, string age)
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("name", name));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("age", age));

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        // When I call this method "PostAsync", the error message is displayed.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.PostAsync("https://api.myhost.com/client/", content);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           // Do something.
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The error started when I added this code: `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;`. I added this code for resolve another error: "417 - Expectation Failed" :(

What you're going?

Thanks...

Comment: What does the www-authenticate header say on the 401 response?

Comment: I receive this header:

Digest realm="Area restrita.",qop="auth",nonce="532c97204bcad",opaque="02c932a49c1224ef22b6726872e674e5"

Comment: Wow.  Good luck.  I've never managed to get digest authentication working.  Try using a CredentialCache instead of just a single simple NetworkCredential.  Although, I'm dubious about the way CredentialCache handles realms.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the authentication mechanism is not responding to the `401 - Unauthorized` response. You can add the PreAuthenticate setting to the HttpClientHandler to force the sending of credentials during the initial request instead of waiting for an authorization challenge.

```
...
// Set authentication.
this.HttpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
this.HttpClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@myemail.com",   "mypassword");
this.HttpClientHandler.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, but it does not work, same error! :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ServicePointManage.Expect100Continue` is not needed. I am assuming that credential not work.

Why not try it via authorization headers:

```
string authInfo = "username@myemail.com:mypassword";
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authInfo);
```